# Android Bitmap Scale

Tags: android, bitmap, scale

I have an ImageView with a size of 400x400.
I would like to scale a Bitmap that the aspect ratio 
is maintained but the longer side is 400!

**Code:**

```
selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
//Calculate and Scale
selectedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(selectedImage, X, Y, false);
imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
```

**Example:**
The Bitmap has a size of 800x400
--> The Bitmap gets scaled --> The result is a Bitmap with size: 400x200

Comment: It is not clear enough. Do you want that longer side of scaled bitmap always be 400, regardless of the original sizes?

Comment: yes. if its smaller it gets stretched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Set your imageview height and width according to your need

```
selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
//Calculate and Scale
selectedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(selectedImage, X, Y, false);
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);  // maintain image dimension to fit in imageview
imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
```